# Given a Principle Conjunctive Normal Form, how can I find all equivalent expressions?

Tags: combinatorics, logic

I can convert  $ (p \lor q) \land (p \lor  r) $ 
to its PCNF:

$(p \lor q \lor r) \land (p \lor q \lor \lnot r) \land (p \lor q \lor r) \land (p \lor \lnot q \lor r)$ ,

How can I get all other equivalent expressions that can be converted to the same PCNF ?

My work: I think the answer is infinite, please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's infinite:

$(p \lor q) \land (p \lor r)$

$(p \lor q) \land (p \lor r) \land (p \lor r)$

$(p \lor q) \land (p \lor r) \land (p \lor r) \land (p \lor r)$

Etc.

Comment: What if we cannot repeat any term like $p \lor r $ in the above (4 line) ? Is it still infinite ?

Comment: @Siddharth Sure. I can do $(p \lor q) \land (p \lor r) \land (s \lor \neg s)$, and $(p \lor q) \land (p \lor r) \land (t \lor \neg t)$, etc.  Or, if you want to stick to $p,q,r$: $(p \lor q \lor (p \land q)) \land (p \lor r)$,  $(p \lor q \lor (p \land (p \lor q))) \land (p \lor r)$, etc.